# How to create TextField for message input with 0 lines?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield, uitextview, textfield

I created `TextField` for message input in chat app. Actually I connected my `TextField` as action (editingChanged). And thats why I can't use `TextView` instead of `TextField`, there is no action I can do with `TextView` in code. If you know how to set 0 lines (just like in labels) in `TextField` and enable scroll. Please help me!

Comment: editingChanged is available in `UITextView` ... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618599-textviewdidchange That too with less effort!

Comment: A `UITextField` is only for one line of text. Period. And why can't you use `UITextView`? It's unclear why you can't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `UITextView` if you want to display multiple lines. The change is not so big, to handle `UITextView` instead of `UITextField`. I will assume that your `UIViewController` is called: `MyViewController`:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate { //1

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView! //2

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textView.delegate = self //3
    }

    func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) { //4
        print(textView.text) //put here your code from textField's action
    }

}
```

1. Remember to add `UITextViewDelegate` protocol to list that your view controller conforms to
2. Add outlet for textView (remember to add it in your storyboard/xib file)
3. Set current view controller as a delegate for textView
4. Add `textViewDidChange` function - use it the same way as you use action for textField